# How to use ColorFilter

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Use ColorFilter for ImageView

Code :

```
  ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imz);
        im.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button);
```

Use Mode.SRC.IN , Mode.MULTIPLY

But  Imageview  has no effect !

Comment: Maybe show some more code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this,

```
 ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imz);   
 im.getDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

The ShapeDrawable for completeness,image size i have fixed size.

circle_white.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

And please do in you layout imageView,

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imz"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_white" />
```

Also try with this also,
[Check Here](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/image-processing-filter-color-channels/)

Comment: it has no effect

Comment: please do something like this

Comment: You can put circle_white according to your image

Comment: it work thanks i use android:background in Imageview ... but now i use android:src thanks you ...

Answer (score -1):

**Please try this**

```
 ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imz);
 im.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: This one is wok for my task